# openmp issue with makefile: "ignoring #pragma omp parallel"

Tags: c++, makefile, openmp

I'm trying to compile the following program using the makefile as shown below on the CELL BE simulator. But I am having a problem with openmp. After the make command, it gives the warning: "ignoring #pragma omp parallel"

//first.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
#pragma omp parallel
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

//Makefile

```
########################################################################
#           Target
########################################################################

PROGRAM_ppu64   = first


########################################################################
#           Local Defines
########################################################################
CFLAGS = -o -fopenmp

########################################################################
#           buildutils/make.footer
########################################################################
include /opt/cell/sdk/buildutils/make.footer
```

//Terminal

```
 $make
 /opt/cell/toolchain/bin/ppu-g++        
 -W -Wall -Winline  -I.  -I /opt/cell/sysroot  
 /usr/include -I /opt/cell/sysroot/opt/cell/sdk/usr/include 
 -mabi=altivec -maltivec     -O3     -c first.cpp
 first.cpp:7: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
 /opt/cell/toolchain/bin/ppu-g++ -o first  first.o      -R/opt/cell/sdk/usr/lib64
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `-fopenmp` is not passed correctly to your compiler. You have set it for `CFLAGS`, try to enable it for `CXXFLAGS` as well, as you are invoking the C++ compiler (g++).

Comment: Besides that, having `-o` in `C(XX)FLAGS` is an error since that option is used to give a name to the output file. Perhaps `-O` was meant in that case?

Comment: yeah, something is definitely fishy in his command line. Anyway, he asked about OpenMP, so I just focued on that ;)

Comment: I tried enabling -fopenmp for C(XX)FLAGS with "-o" option enabled and disabled as suggested by @Hristo, still I'm getting the same warning.

Comment: @Shail, I hope you didn't actually set `C(XX)FLAGS` as this is merely a shorthand notation for both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. Also `-o` (lower-case O) on its own is plain wrong and it should probably be `-O` (upper-case O)